# A simple unit test library for C

Tags: c, unit-testing, library, assertions

(This post is followed up by [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289599/a-simple-unit-test-library-for-c-version-ii).)

I have rolled this simple unit test library for C:

**`com_github_coderodde_my_assert.h`:**

```
#ifndef COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_MY_ASSERT_H
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_MY_ASSERT_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern size_t passes;
extern size_t failed;

void print_test_statistics();

#define ASSERT_IMPL(COND, LINE) assert_impl(COND, #COND, __LINE__);
#define ASSERT(COND) ASSERT_IMPL(COND, __LINE__)

#endif
```

**`com_github_coderodde_my_assert.c`:**

```
#include "com_github_coderodde_my_assert.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

static size_t passes = 0;
static size_t failed = 0;

void assert_impl(bool passed,
                        const char* condition_text,
                        size_t line_number) {
    if (passed) {
        passes++;
    } else {
        failed++;

        printf("Failed condition \"%s\" at line %zu.\n",
            condition_text,
            line_number);
    }
}

static void print_bar(size_t passes, size_t failed) {
    size_t total_assertions = passes + failed;
    
    char bar[81];

    bar[0] = '[';
    bar[79] = ']';
    bar[80] = '\0';

    float ratio = (float)(passes) / (float)(total_assertions);

    size_t hash_symbols = (size_t)(78 * ratio);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < hash_symbols; i++) {
        bar[i + 1] = '#';
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 78 - hash_symbols; i++) {
        bar[i + 1 + hash_symbols] = ' ';
    }

    if (failed != 0) {
        printf("\033[0;31m");
        printf("%s: %.2f%%.\n", bar, 100.0f * ratio);
    } else {
        printf("\033[0;32m");
        printf("%s: %.2F%%.\n", bar, 100.0f * ratio);
    }

    printf("\033[0m");
}

void print_test_statistics() {
    printf("Passes: %zu, failures: %zu, total assertions: %zu.\n",
           passes,
           failed,
           passes + failed);

    print_bar(passes, failed);
}
```

**`main.c`:**

```
#include "com_github_coderodde_my_assert.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    ASSERT(true);
    ASSERT(false);
    ASSERT(1 + 1 == 3);

    print_test_statistics();

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

## Critique request

As always, I would love to hear any comments on how to improve my result.

Answer (score 7):

The header doesn't need to include anything except `<stddef.h>` (to define `size_t`).

---

These two externs are never used:

> ```
> extern size_t passes;
> extern size_t failed;
> ```

We should just delete them - or perhaps change the shadowing declarations in the implementation file to refer to these globals instead.

---

Test output should go to `stderr` rather than being mixed in with program results.  Consider printing the file name as well as line number, so the usual tools can take users straight to the error location.

---

Please use a suitable variable for this size (or derive the related values using `sizeof bar`):

> ```
> char bar[81];
> ```

As it stands, there's too many places that need to be consistently modified if this value is adjusted.

---

We have a string here that assumes a specific output device:

> ```
>     printf("\033[0;31m");
> ```

That looks a mess on other terminal types, and hampers parsing when output is not a terminal.

---

The `main()` always returns a success status, even when one or more tests fail.  That's wrong, and makes it hard to use this test suite as part of a larger build process.

Comment: I'm not OP, but could you elaborate on how you would do the coloring instead? What's a good way to display color in your terminal, but not screw up other outputs?

Comment: @Opifex, you need to examine `TERM` environment variable and perhaps test `isatty()`.  Or use a library such as Termcap or Curses that does those things for you.