# A simple unit test library for C - version II

Tags: c, unit-testing, library, assertions

I have improved my code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289581/a-simple-unit-test-library-for-c) and it looks like this:

## Code

**`assertlib.h:`**

```
#ifndef COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_ASSERTLIB_H
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_ASSERTLIB_H

void print_test_statistics();
int get_exit_status();

#define ASSERT_IMPL(COND, FILE, LINE) assert_impl(COND, #COND, FILE, LINE);
#define ASSERT(COND) ASSERT_IMPL(COND, __FILE__, __LINE__)

#endif
```

**`assertlib.c:`**

```
#include "assertlib.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COMPLETION_BAR_LENGTH 80

static size_t passes = 0;
static size_t failed = 0;

void assert_impl(bool passed,
                 const char* condition_text,
                 const char* file_name,
                 size_t line_number) {
    if (passed) {
        passes++;
    } else {
        failed++;

        fprintf(stderr, 
                "Failed condition \"%s\" in file \"%s\" at line %zu.\n",
                condition_text,
                file_name,
                line_number);
    }
}

int get_exit_status() {
    return failed == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}

static void print_bar(size_t bar_length) {
    size_t total_assertions = passes + failed;

    char* bar = calloc(bar_length + 16, sizeof(char));

    if (bar == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    bar[0] = '[';
    bar[bar_length + 1] = ']';

    float ratio = (float)(passes) / (float)(total_assertions);

    size_t hash_symbols = (size_t)(bar_length * ratio);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < hash_symbols; i++) {
        bar[i + 1] = '#';
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bar_length - hash_symbols; i++) {
        bar[i + 1 + hash_symbols] = '.';
    }

    printf("%s: %.2f%%.\n", bar, 100.0f * ratio);
    free(bar);
}

void print_test_statistics() {
    printf("Passes: %zu, failures: %zu, total assertions: %zu.\n",
           passes,
           failed,
           passes + failed);

    print_bar(COMPLETION_BAR_LENGTH);
}
```

**`main.c:`**

```
#include "assertlib.h"

int main()
{
    ASSERT(1 + 1 == 2);
    ASSERT(1);
    ASSERT(1 != 1);
    ASSERT(1 + 2 == 3);

    print_test_statistics();

    return get_exit_status();
}
```

## Unit test output

The output looks like this:

```
Failed condition "1 != 1" in file "C:\Users\rodio\Documents\VSProjects\assertlib.h\main.c" at line 7.
Passes: 3, failures: 1, total assertions: 4.
[############################################################....................]: 75.00%.
```

## Critique request

As always, I would like to hear anything that comes to mind.

Comment: It appears we could elide ASSERT_IMPL. Looks good otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, `void get_exit_status()` declares a function that takes an unspecified number of parameters, not a function that takes none.

If the function expects no arguments, it should be defined with the keyword `void`, unless you are compiling with `C2X`, where empty parentheses defines a function that takes no arguments, akin to C++. In which case you should also remove the inclusion of `stdbool.h`, as `bool`, `true`, and `false` are keywords in C23.

You also do not require the inclusion of `stddef.h`, as `stdio.h` already declares `size_t`.

---

As `print_bar()` is always passed in `COMPLETION_BAR_LENGTH`, we can do away with the call to `calloc()` and replace it with a fixed-size array:

```
#if 0
char* bar = calloc(bar_length + 16, sizeof(char));
#else
char bar[COMPLETION_BAR_LENGTH + 16] = {0};
#endif
```

Though I do not see why the memory needs to be zero-initialized, especially when it is overwritten right after its initialization.

---

Note that `sizeof(char)` is defined by the C standard to be 1, so you can safely replace it with 1.

---

Consider conditionally dealing with `passed` and returning early in `assert_impl()`.

That way you can deal with `failed` unconditionally, saving four spaces of indent.